# Can cryptsetup read mappings from /etc/crypttab?

Tags: disk-encryption, luks

I have a virtualized CentOS 7 server that needs to mount multiple password-protected encrypted volumes. I cannot automatically map the devices on boot, because I don't have access to the console during the boot process to enter the decryption password. After I reboot the system, I have to manually run

```
cryptsetup luksOpen <device> <name>
```

to map each underlying block device to an encrypted device. That requires keeping notes on the UUID of each underlying block device and the name it maps to. Is there an easy way to automate this process? I can add the information to `/etc/crypttab` with the `noauto` keyword to prevent the devices from mounting on boot. However, I can't get cryptsetup to use the information from this file.

It would be great if there were a command like `cryptsetup luksOpen <name>` that would read `/etc/crypttab` to find the name of the underlying block device (similar to the way that you can can `mount <mountpoint>` if  is defined in `/etc/fstab`).

Is there any way to get cryptsetup to read the mappings from `/etc/crypttab`?

Answer (score 10):

You can use

`sudo systemctl start systemd-cryptsetup@<name>`

instead of

`cryptsetup luksOpen UUID=... <name>`

when you have an entry as follows in your /etc/crypttab:

`<name> UUID=... none noauto`

It will prompt you for the passphrase if needed.

The corresponding unit file is generated automatically by [systemd-cryptsetup-generator](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup-generator.html).

You can list all generated unit files using

`systemctl list-unit-files| grep systemd-cryptsetup`

Comment: You can run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after editing `/etc/crypttab` to re-generate the units.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [cryptdisks_start](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/cryptdisks_start.8.html) and [cryptdisks_stop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/cryptdisks_stop.8.html), they do exactly that.

```
# cryptdisks_start <name>
# mount <mountpoint>
...stuff...
# umount <mountpoint>
# cryptdisks_stop <name>
```

Comment: These Debian-isms are not available on most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to experiment with [`systemd-cryptsetup-generator`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup-generator.html).

Normally this process runs during the initramfs boot, to dynamically generate [systemd units that decrypt each block device](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup@.service.html) listed in `/etc/crypttab`. You can then start those units whenever you wish, and you'll be prompted for any necessary passphrases.

Since this is a virtual machine, you *should* have access to the virtual console, meaning you could simply encrypt your filesystems normally and provide the passphrase at boot. Of course, the [security of the encrypted filesystems is compromised anyway](https://serverfault.com/a/484715/126632), simply by being used in a virtual machine, regardless of when you enter the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

I made a bash script specifically for this case,
it parses `crypttab` to retrieve the uuid of device to open/close,
afterwards it uses `fstab` to store mount options.

As a convention I mount the encrypted device in the root folder on a directory named like the device node in `/dev/mapper` but capitalized;
for example, a device named `xsnl` in crypttab will mount on `/Xsnl`.

NB: you will need to use `noauto` option in both `fstab` and `crypttab`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

usage(){
  echo "usage:   ./crypt.sh [open|close] <encrypted_dev>"
}

OP=$1
TARGET=$2

# we bail out in case no first argument is passed
if [[ $OP != 'close' ]] && [[ $OP != 'open' ]]; then
  usage
  echo "Exiting: first argument must be either 'lock' or 'unlock'."
  exit
fi

# we bail out in case no second argument is passed
if [[ -z $TARGET ]]; then
  usage
  echo "Exiting: second argument must be the name of the entry in fstab."
  exit
fi

# our convention is to give same name to fstab mount point (upperfirst) and crypttab name (lower)
MAPPDEV=$(echo $TARGET | awk '{print tolower($0)}')

ENCRYPTED_DEV=$(sudo grep -w $MAPPDEV /etc/crypttab)

# we bail out if we don't match a device in crypttab
if [[ -z $ENCRYPTED_DEV ]]; then
  usage
  echo "Exiting: no device named $MAPPDEV found in crypttab."
  exit
fi

SEC_FIELD=$( echo $ENCRYPTED_DEV | sed -r 's/\s+/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f2)

# now we have all the info,
# depending on $OP (operation mode) we decide what to do
if [[ $OP == 'close' ]]; then
  sudo umount /$TARGET
  sudo cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPDEV
  exit
fi

# if we get here we need to open and mount
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen $SEC_FIELD $MAPPDEV
sudo mount /$TARGET
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/fracalo/c42cb185431c8cfd97420a0b3d64d672)