# MySQL encryption at rest

Tags: mysql, encryption, mariadb

Context: Rackspace CloudServers.

The options I can find are rather slim. Amazon will encrypt the whole disk (meh), Gazzang could encrypt a virtual partition with just the DB files on it (if the company was still around), I could encrypt the data at the column level (no good, can't search)... or I could use MariaDB.

I desperately want MySQL 5.7.9's JSON column, but it seems like MariaDB is my only good encryption option.

Is there a good option other than MariaDB for table-level encryption?
Is MariaDB's encryption a good solution?
Is at-rest encryption in a cloud environment really worth it?

Comment: MariaDB supports dynamic columns including a json format (`COLUMN_JSON`) + tablespace encryption. MariaDB is also faster and more stable, I have abondoned native MySQL several years ago (in business and private) and I didn't regret it.
1. MariaDB 2. Percona 3. native MySQL

Comment: Btw. [Colin Charles has been talking](https://www.codetalks.de/2015/programm/security-for-mariadb-mysql-mariadb-mysql-security-essentials) about all this and if you really need a GOOD answer, go and try to contact him (he is a MariaDB developer).

Comment: For your last question, see http://serverfault.com/a/484715/126632

Comment: It looks like MariaDB is planning on using MySQL 5.7's JSON. https://speakerdeck.com/rasmushoj/mariadb-roadmap-session?slide=4

Answer (score 1):

As hinted to in the comments to the question, MariaDB was planning to implement a JSON data type, and indeed they now have (sort of). As of MariaDB 10.2.7 there is now a JSON data type (which is an alias for LONGTEXT). See the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/) for details.

As of MySQL 5.7.11 there is also a [InnoDB tablespace encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html) feature. [MariaDB has supported at-rest encryption](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/data-at-rest-encryption/) since version 10.1.3.

The Percona Blog did a comparison of [MariaDB and MySQL at-rest encryption](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/04/08/mysql-data-at-rest-encryption/) back in 2016. In my view MariaDB comes out favourably here as it can encrypt not only tables, but also redo/undo logs, binary/relay logs. Note that while Percona Xtrabackup doesn't support MariaDB's encryption, MariaDB Backup (a fork of Xtrabackup) does.